# Can you parent a bug under an epic?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Is there anything wrong with making a Bug work item the direct Child of an Epic work item?

We are using the "Bugs are managed with requirements" configuration in Azure DevOps so we prioritize bugs alongside requirements and create tasks under them.

It seems in this configuration all the documentation show bugs being children of features as the logical parent, or unparented. I can link an Epic as the parent of the bug, and nothing is wrong (it actually works great on the Delivery Plans).

But of course, you cannot:

- Use the mapping pane in the backlog to map a bug to an epic (this also is only designed to allow you to map to a Feature)
- See these bugs in the Epic view of the Boards (kanban) area

What I'm trying to avoid is creating an unnecessary feature work item as a layer in the hierarchy, say if:

- Epic - version 1.0

  - Feature - feature a

    - Requirement 1
    - Requirement 2
    - Bug 1
    - Bug 2
  - Feature - feature b
  - Feature - service pack <--- unnecessary layer, especially in rollups

    - Bug 1
    - Bug 2

Where instead I could do:

- Epic - version 1.0
- Feature - feature a

  - Requirement 1
  - Requirement 2
  - Bug 1
  - Bug 2
- Feature - feature b
- Bug 1
- Bug 2

**Example Parenting Bug Under Feature**
If I parent the bug directly under the epic, I don't have the extra feature, which is great. The screenshot below shows the default configuration of parenting the bug under the epic, which creates 2 features instead of 1.

[image]

Comment: Are you raising bugs when QA find a problem with the deliverable? i.e. the Feature lists a bunch of acceptance criteria, and the QA's fail one of more of these? Or are these bugs found elsewhere, but were introduced as part of the feature you're parenting them to?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have the exact same issue, and so far I have only worked around it by creating a feature only to change its type to a bug. This works, but I am then unable to move the bug to another epic.

Comment: You can link an epic to a bug as a parent, my Q is more whether this is appropriate by design of DevOps and if it will cause anything to not work properly. None of the documentation shows this kind of hierarchy. For now, I have remained using features in between and called them Service Packs for tracking a collection of bugs for a release. We also switched to using tags for version numbers instead of iteration paths, using those truly for all the sprints for the year